# Jest errors when using it to test vuejs/typescript components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I used the vue cli 3 to create an app with typescript and jest for unit test. But I got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Any explinations ? (I didn't change nothing in jest.config or tsconfig)

BTW if a change lang="ts" to lang="js" it works.

Code component (Simpliste component possible):

```
<template>
    <div>{{hello}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    data () {
        return {
            message: 'hello'
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Test file

```
import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';

import AComp from '@/components/uikit/AComp.vue';

describe('DropdownButton', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(AComp);
    });

    it("works", () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy()
    })
});
```